# 'CreateThread' crashes with more than 2 threads

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I need a new pair of eyes on my code because I cannot figure out why the code crashes.

Here is a pretty straight forward block of code for creating a number of threads:

```
arrayThread = (int*)malloc(NUM_OF_THREADS * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
    {
       f_vars.begin_simulations = (int)i*(no_of_simulations / NUM_OF_THREADS);
       f_vars.end_simulations   = (int)(i+1)*(no_of_simulations / NUM_OF_THREADS)-1;

       arrayThread[i] = _beginthreadex(NULL,
                                       0,
                                       functionPtr,
                                       &f_vars,
                                       0,
                                       &ThreadId);

       if (arrayThread[i] == NULL)
       {
           printf("Create Thread %d get failed. Error no: %d", i, GetLastError);
       }
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(NUM_OF_THREADS, arrayThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(arrayThread[i]);
    }
```

Problem:

The code crashes at line "arrayThread[i] = _beginthreadex". But not always. Sometimes it runs till the end. When I debug via "printf" then the probability is very high that the code finishes successfully.
I have not yet seen an error when NUM_OF_THREADS = 2, sometimes when NUM_OF_THREADS = 3 and often, when
NUM_OF_THREADS > 3.

I intentionally didn't post a longer piece of code in order to keep it simple.

If there is more you need I'll provide more code. Maybe some issue already jumps at you while reading
this piece?

Thank you!

I have no further idea what to try.

Comment: Please show how you create the arguments to _beginthreadex

Comment: `arrayThread = (int*)malloc(NUM_OF_THREADS * sizeof(int));` communicates that you want to store ints, however, _beginthreadex seems to return `uintptr_t`

Comment: Seriously: Doing C programming without paying attention to _type_ s will make your programming life hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocate an array of `int` (4 bytes in Windows), but `_beginthreadex` returns a `uintptr_t` (8 bytes in a 64-bit Windows program).

The documentation suggests you cast the result to a `HANDLE` so that you can cleanly pass it to `WaitForMultipleObjects` and `CloseHandle`.

Adjust the type of `arrayThread` and the amount of memory allocated accordingly.

```c
HANDLE *threads = malloc( sizeof( HANDLE ) * NUM_OF_THREADS );
```

```c
uintptr_t h = _beginthreadex( ... )
if ( !h ) {
   // Error handling.
}

threads[ i ] = (HANDLE)h;
```

Comment: And `WaitForMultipleObjects()` expects a `const HANDLE *` for its second argument.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Not actually an issue except for warnings since they're the same size, but I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: I'd replace `sizeof( HANDLE )` with `sizeof *threads` to make the allocating expression crystal clear, but you got my vote anyway.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo That's no better. That's why I would actually use a macro (such as `#define MALLOC(t, n) ( (t*)malloc(sizeof(t) * n) )`) that actually addresses the problem. Otherwise, I use the type, like we do in every other language.

Comment: @ikegami Cool that we have different takes on it. I think your original is more complex to parse for a human than my suggestion, which is why I'd use my version in any language (witch supports the syntax of course).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, In C++, you use the type  (`new type`). Same goes for C# (`new Type`), JS (`new Type`), Perl (`Type->new`), Python (`Type()`), Java, PHP, Ruby, ...? You don't even have a choice.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not trying to find a set. In languages with user managed memory, support I prefer to _express_ what I'm allocating.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Re "*I prefer to express what I'm allocating.*", That's what I do. I'm allocating a `HANDLE`, so that's what I use in my `malloc`. So why did you suggest doing the opposite?

Comment: @ikegami I did not. I suggested allocating memory for what was declared. I guess this is a discussion for coffee breaks :-)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Anyway, it's moot, since neither of those approaches are safe. It's a false dichotomy. The macro above makes it safe. (The compiler will warn or worse if you make an error.)

Comment: @ikegami I'd prefer `sizeof` _`expression`_  with a multiplier that multiple type specifications almost(!) every time, and if neither is safe, I'd still adhere to the one that "read"s best.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, Re "*if neither is safe*", One is safe. And it reads best. `MALLOC( HANDLE, n )`

Comment: @ikegami Both are safe at the time the line was written. One is safe when the type changes.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, Re "*Both are safe at the time the line was written*", Both *work if there's no error*. That doesn't make them *safe.* Safe means errors are detected.

Comment: @ikegami _"doesn't make them safe"_ - I have not qualm about that. It's a language where memory is supposed to be managed by the coder. Nothing is safe in that respect. It's _safer_ to declare intent and _express_ it.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, You're being very disingenuous. Why not just use `void*` for everything then. No. C does provide type checks. And arguing you shouldn't use them is silly. I don't believe you compile without warnings, which your last comment argues against.  /// Re "*It's safer to declare intent and express it.*", No, it's safer to let the compiler catch the error. And that's why your suggestion doesn't solve anything. Failing that, I do believe it's *more readable* to declare intent and express it, so that's why I did. I wanted to allocate an array of HANDLEs, so I did.

Comment: @ikegami I see that we see this differently (hence my "coffee break" suggestion).
_"arguing you shouldn't use them is silly"_ - I'm not. I'm arguing using _the one_ declaration to provide information for the expression in the allocation. It's not a contradiction, quite the opposite.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, You indicated we shouldn't strive to make it not error prone. That's what I called "silly". It's perfectly doable here. At no cost. It's even far more readable.

Comment: @ikegami It _is_ safer  and more readable than what you suggest in the world where you want to allocate memory for what you declare a pointer to.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, No it's not. The compiler will not detect the error. This isn't subjective. What you suggest is objectively less safe than the macro. And note that you can use `typeof` with the macro if you don't want to repeat the type. Doesn't gain you anything, but doesn't really cost anything. *That* is just a style pref.

Comment: @ikegami A macro could help make it more readable. If you provided it in the comments, I missed it and appologise. It's not in the Q or A though.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo 4th comment.

Comment: @ikegami Brilliant! - I thought it was about my `sizeof expression` suggestion all the time.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yeah, no. False dichotomy and all that.

Comment: @ikegami I don't see the need to be unfriendly. I _try_ to give as accurate information and advice as I can and it's always the best that I can give. My comment was a reflection of that.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I wasn't? I mean, right from the start, I lead the friendly "Yeah, no."  I was just pointing I was talking about the macro all along, as evidenced by the earlier statement that choosing between `malloc( sizeof(type) * ...  )` and `malloc( sizeof(*var) * ...  )` is a false dichotomy. I had also mentioned `MALLOC( HANDLE, n )`. etc

Comment: The macro also works with C23 `auto`: `auto p = MALLOC( int, 4 );`

Answer (score -1):

Ah yes, guys, thank you very much. That was it!

I changed

```c
int *arrayThread;
arrayThread = (int*)malloc(NUM_OF_THREADS * sizeof(int));
```

to

```c
uintptr_t *arrayThread;
arrayThread = (int*)malloc(NUM_OF_THREADS * sizeof(uintptr_t));
```

And now it works reliably.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo To be fair, my answer didn't include code (or mention HANDLE) when this answer was posted. (I added to my answer at virtually the same time this was posted.)

Comment: @ikegami I can see how that works and lifeted my downvote (and explanation for it).

Comment: I must add: The answer is wrong. The `(int*)` cast destroys everything. So, my downvote is back again.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, `(int*)` is wrong, but it doesn't "destroy everything." (i.e. the code will work) since all pointers have the same format in Windows.

Comment: @ikegami "in Windows" is just what makes it wrong. The cast to `int*` should unconditionally be removed.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Re "*"in Windows" is just what makes it wrong.*", `_beginthreadex` is a Windows system call... /// Re "*The cast to `int*` should unconditionally be removed.*" Absolutely. I did say it was wrong.

Comment: @ikegami I objected to `(int*) malloc(...)`. Why promote that as being correct?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo. I didn't. I said it's wrong in every single comments. ("`(int*)` is wrong". "I did say [the cast to `int*`] was wrong." "[The cast to `int*` should] Absolutely [unconditionally be removed]")